# Updating a mysql column using a php loop

Tags: php, mysql

I need to update the initial values of a mysql column, a tokens column, at the beginning, those values are all null, then, they need to be updated, with a tokens generating function, how am doing it, it just doesn´t updates any values, see:

```
$query = "SELECT `id` FROM `acuses_recibo` WHERE `id_envio`=101 AND `token` IS NULL";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

here I select the id´s of those null tokens for an specific id_envio, then

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){//as long as there are token null values
  foreach($row as $id=>$row['id']){
    $indice = $row['id'];
    $v=getToken(32);
    echo $v.PHP_EOL;
    echo "id es: ".$row['id'].PHP_EOL;
    $queryDos = "UPDATE `acuses_recibo` SET `token`={$v} WHERE `id`={$indice} ";
    mysqli_query($conn, $queryDos);
}
```

where `getToken(32)` calculates a token of length 32, this way no token is updated, the only way they get updated is if I set `token`in `$queryDos` to a fixed value, how could I remedy this in such a way that every token value gets updated? thanx i.a.

Comment: Last night there was an answer, now that I comeback to my code, voila! the answer is gone!, if someone did answer, but then decided to delete it, could you be as nice as to say why was the answer deleted?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it, I separated the problem in two parts, the first just selects all the `id`´s for a specific `id_envio` as follows

```
$query = "SELECT `id` FROM `acuses_recibo` WHERE `id_envio`=101 AND `token` IS NULL";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
// an arrays is created and used to store the id´s selected
$members = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
$members[] = array('id'=> $row['id']);
}
// the connection is then closed, something I found on mysql not being explicitly multiconnection
mysqli_close($conn);
// then a new connection is setup
$connDos = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
```

Now, the token values are updated as follows, please note that `$indice` has to be cast to int type because the array fetched returns strings

```
foreach($members as $m){
  $indice = $m["id"];
  $indice = intval($indice);
  $voken=getToken(32);
  $queryDos = " UPDATE `acuses_recibo` SET `token`='{$voken}' WHERE   `id`='{$indice}' ";
  if (mysqli_query($connDos, $queryDos)) {
    echo "Record updated successfully".PHP_EOL;
  } else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($connDos).PHP_EOL;
  }

}
```

then, the second connection is closed

```
mysqli_close($connDos);
```

and this is how I could update the token values to their calculated values. I hope it helps somebody.